# How to install xsane scanner?

Tags: scanner, xsane

How do I install xsane scanner? Is it by running this command from a Terminal?

```
apt-get install sane sane-utils libsane-extras xsane
```

My scanner: PIXMA MG3500

Comment: @user68186 How do I find it? It used to be there, but no more

Comment: @user68186 Problem solved, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my comments:

## Simple Scan

Install Simple Scan if it is not installed. Open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo apt install simple-scan
```

This will install Simple Scan and all its dependencies.

If this does not work you may try installing the `snap` version with:

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install simple-scan
```

I have not used the snap version.

Hope this helps